# Lebesgue points of a set

Tags: measure-theory

Recall that given a locally integrable function $f$ for the Lebesgue measure $\mathcal{L}^d$ we have that,
$$\lim_{r\to 0} \frac{1}{\mathcal{L}^d(B(x,r))} \int_{B(x,r)} |f(z)-f(x)|dz =0$$
for almost every $x\in \Omega$ where the open set $\Omega\subset \mathbb{R}^d.$ The points $x$ for which the above equality holds are called the Lebesgue points of the function $f$. We denote $\operatorname{Leb}(f)$ as the set of all Lebesgue points of the function $f\in L^{1}_{\operatorname{loc}}(\mathbb{R}^d).$

To define the Lebesgue points of a $\mathcal{L}^d$ measurable set $A$ we simply use the indicator function $f=1_{A}$ and thus $\operatorname{Leb}(A) = \operatorname{Leb}(1_{A})$ or in other words $x\in \operatorname{Leb}(A)$ if,
\begin{align}
\lim_{r\to 0} \frac{\mathcal{L}^d(A\cap B(x,r))}{\mathcal{L}^d(B(x,r))}=1.
\end{align}

With these two definitions, here is my **question**: If $\mu << \mathcal{L}^d$ and $f$ is the density function of $\mu,$
\begin{align}
f(y)=\limsup_{r\to 0} \frac{\mu(B(y,r))}{\mathcal{L}^d(B(y,r))},
\end{align}
and for some $x\in\Omega$ we have $f(x)>0$ and $x\in \operatorname{Leb}(f),$ then why is $x\in \operatorname{Leb}(A)$ where $A=\{y\in \Omega: f(y)>0\} = \{f>0\}?$

Here is what I think. To show that $x\in \operatorname{Leb}(A)$ we need to show that
\begin{align}
\lim_{r\to 0} \frac{\mathcal{L}^d(A\cap B(x,r))}{\mathcal{L}^d(B(x,r))}=1.
\end{align}
Now $x\in A$ since $f(x)>0$ and so $x\in A\cap B(x,r),$ but this not very helpful. If $x$ was a point of continuity of $f$ then the proof is trivial since I can find a ball around $x$ where $f>0$ and so limit expression would be equal to $1.$ But this is not the case here. Any comments or hints are much appreciated.

**Edit: ** I came across this fact while reading the proof of Lemma 3.5 in the following article [Monge Problem in R^d](http://cvgmt.sns.it/media/doc/paper/346/champion-depascale.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

This is false.

Let $A$ be any set such that $0$ is not a Lebesgue point of $A$.

Let $f(t)=|t|\chi_A(t)$, so $f\ge0$ and $A=\{f>0\}$. Then $f$ is continuous at the origin, so $0$ *is* a Lebesgue point of $f$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I see why this claim is false. However, the author in the article that I mentioned above makes use of this fact in the proof of Lemma 3.5 (Pg 7). I guess that must be a mistake then?